# Async function in javascript stops executing all by itself

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Here I have an async function in javascript that is used to fill up the sudoku board with numbers (basically its solution). I used a sleeper function between each number insertion so that the user can get a better feel of the recursion and backtracking algorithm, however after the fifteenth number gets inserted, the function stops by itself... What is going on here exactly ?

```
var finalInd;

function sleep() {
    console.log("happy")
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
}


async function solve () {

    allowed = false;
    var empty = findEmptySpace();

    if(!empty) {
        return true;
    }

    for(let i=1; i<10; i++) {

        if(checkDuplicates(board, i, empty)) {

            board[empty[0]][empty[1]] = i;
            finalInd = (empty[0]*9) + empty[1];

            await sleep()
            funcId("board").children[finalInd].innerHTML = i;

            if(solve(board)) {
                return true;
            }
            
            board[empty[0]][empty[1]] = 0;
            
            funcId("board").children[finalInd].innerHTML = 0;
        }
    }

    funcId("board").children[0].innerHTML = board[0][0];
    return false;

}


function checkDuplicates (board, num, empty) {
    for(let i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if(board[empty[0]][i] == num && empty[1] != i) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(let i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if(board[i][empty[1]] == num && empty[0] != i) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    var x = Math.floor(empty[1]/3);
    var y = Math.floor(empty[0]/3);

    for(let i=(y*3); i<(y*3)+3; i++) {
        for(let j=(x*3); j<(x*3)+3; j++) {
            if(board[i][j] == num && i != empty[0] && j != empty[1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;

}


function findEmptySpace () {

    for(let i=0; i<9; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j<9; j++) {
            if(board[i][j] == 0) {
                return [i, j];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Pic of first 15 nums filled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to `await` the recursive call to `solve`, so it will always return a promise, which it's truthy, and your function will terminate.

Comment: Could you please explain the last part of what you said ? Here the only promise returned is the wait for 100ms . How does a recursive function create an issue for that, I dont really understand

Comment: Your function `solve` is declared `async`, which means that it returns a promise. The keywords `async` and `await` are syntactic sugar for promises even if you don't write the word `Promise` explicitly. So `solve` returns a promise that resolves as a boolean. But every promise is truthy (because it's an object and every object is truthy), so `if (solve(board)) {...}` will always run the code inside the `if`.

Comment: You can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function for more information.